# Downgrading from OpenSSL 3.0.2 to 1.1.1 - How much can stuff break?

Tags: apt, openssl, dependencies, pop-os

I recently upgraded to Pop!_OS (Ubuntu derivative) 22.04 and it ships with OpenSSL 3.0.2, which poses a problem:

Unity (the game engine) expects 1.1.1

spotify-tui expects 1.1.1

and much more software expects 1.1.1 whereas I have 3.0.2.

Now, OpenSSL 1.1.1 is available in Pop!_OS repositories by going to the repository address from a browser and downloading the 1.1.1 deb.

And I could just install the 1.1.1 deb and `apt-mark hold` the package. But I'm pretty sure that's gonna break *something*. I just don't know what.

What could be broken and how much by downgrading OpenSSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need to downgrade OpenSSL, versions 1.1 and 3.0 are co-installable. You can keep `libssl3` installed, and install `libssl1.1` alongside it. Programs built using OpenSSL 3.0 will use the former, programs built using 1.1 will use the latter.

Note that you’ll have to keep track of security updates to `libssl1.1` yourself.